# SQL Server JOIN not working

Tags: sql-server, join

I am not sure why the below join query is not returning any results.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2  ON table1.fieldid = table2.idfield
```

The below 2 queries return results so I am not sure why the join wont pick up any rows when i can clearly see that both tables have join field values in common.

```
SELECT *  FROM table1 WHERE fieldid =  900399530  (returns rows)
SELECT *  FROM table2 WHERE idfield =  900399530  (returns rows)
```

Any ideas?

Below are the data types for the 2 columns:

> fieldid [nvarchar] (50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL
>
> idfield [nvarchar] (255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL

Comment: what are the datatype of both columns?

Comment: Can you show us a demo of your table definition and sample data where this fails?

Comment: Try it by using single quotes: '900399530'. Maybe there is some extra space in any of your tables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as it's a CHAR/VARCHAR/NVARCHAR field you should use single quotes:

Maybe there is some extra or leading space.

Try it on this way:

```
SELECT *  FROM table1 WHERE fieldid =  '900399530';
SELECT *  FROM table2 WHERE idfield =  '900399530';
```

or remove additional spaces by using [TRIM()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql) function.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 JOIN table2  ON TRIM(table1.fieldid) = TRIM(table2.idfield);
```

For versions below 2017:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1
JOIN   table2
ON     LTRIM(RTRIM(table1.fieldid)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(table2.idfield));
```

Comment: looks like you are right. when i add the single quotes , table 2 no longer returns any records. I will trim the fields in both tables as it does appear there are some spaces in there. if the join works after that ,i'll come back and accept your answer. Thanks!!

Comment: Standard SQL ignores trailing spaces for comparison but leading spaces are significant.